# Problemas em adicionar ação no Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, mysql, zend

Estou com dificuldades em adicionar uma música que contém no álbum, quero fazer com que, quando eu adicionar uma música, já esteja relacionada com o id do álbum.

Meu problema é no método adicionarMúsica() abaixo:

**MusicasController:**

```
public function adicionarAction() {
    $forms = new Application_Form_FormMusicas();
    $forms->submit->setLabel('Adicionar');
    $this->view->form = $forms;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($forms->isValid($formData)) {
                                            
            $idmusica = $forms->getValue('idmusica');

            $musica = $forms->getValue('musica');
            $duracao = $forms->getValue('duracao');

            $musicas = new Application_Model_DbTable_Musicas();
            $musicas->adicionarMusica($musica, $duracao, $idmusica);

            $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'idmusica');
        } else {
            $forms->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui está outras informações que talvez possam auxiliam na ajuda:

**Banco de Dados:**

Tabelas:

*--albums--*

id INT PRIMARY KEY

artist varchar(40)

title varchar(40)

*--musicas--*

id INT PRIMARY KEY

musica VARCHAR(40)

duracao varchar(40)

idmusica int FOREIGN KEY de albums(id)

**Application_Model_DbTable_Musicas:**

```
  protected $dbt;
  protected $_name = 'musicas';
  protected $_primary = 'id';

protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'RelacionamentoTabelas' => array(
        'columns' => 'idmusica',
        'refTableClass' => 'Application_Model_DbTable_Albums',
        'refColumns' => 'id'
    ),
);

public function adicionarMusica($musica, $duracao, $idalbum) {
   
    //$novoid = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
    //$id = (int) $novoid->setValue('id');
    $data = array(
        'musica' => $musica,
        'duracao' => $duracao,
        'idmusica' => $idalbum
    );
    $this->insert($data);

}
```

**Application_Model_DbTable_Albums**

```
protected $_name = 'albums';

protected $_primary = 'id';

protected $_dependentTables = array('Application_Model_DbTable_Musicas');
```

chamada na view para adicionar as músicas direto do id do album:

ps.: verifiquem no 'id' onde eu pego o id do album e passo logo direto para ser armarzenado com a chave estrangeira, mas acho que está errado.

**index.phtml:**

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'musicas', 
            'action'=>'adicionar', 'id' => $album->id));?>">Adicionar música</a></td>
```

Todos os outros métodos estão funcionando, menos esse!

Comment: Pelo o que eu vi, você está passando o id do álbum (idmusica) pela url (GET) mas está pegando o valor pelo formulário em `$idmusica = $forms->getValue('idmusica');`. Você possui um campo hidden no formulário para o id do álbum?

Comment: Você diz adicionar um campo hidden do id do álbum no formulário da música ou no formulário do album? eu adicionei no formulário do album assim: 
`$id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');`

E no form da música coloquei seu id e sua chave estrangeira como hidden também:

  `$id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');

        $idalbum = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('idalbum');
        $id->addFilter('Int');`

O problema justamente é em adicionar o idalbum no adicionarAction. Não tenho que chamar uma function para buscar o id do album?

Comment: Ei, agora que percebi que o nome no campo hidden estava errado (idalbum para idmusica), mas olha só ainda está dando problema, você acha que minha chave estrangeira deve ser NULL? A minha está como NOT NULL. Abraços.

Comment: O que está sendo salvo no campo idmusica? Eu acho que o problema é que o id do álbum não está vindo preenchido no formulário. Verifique isso ou me corrija se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Está sendo salva um int que é o mesmo do campo id da tabela musicas. Você diz, por exemplo, fazer um Hidden no id do album no formulário do Album ou da Musica? Se for isso eu fiz, no form do Album aqui está o código: `$id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');` E dei addElements também `$this->addElements(array($id, $artist, $title, $submit));`. O que eu acho que está errado é esse index.phtml quando vou invocar o adicionarAction no controller música, quando eu faço $album->id, ele já automaticamente liga à chave estrangeira idalbum? Fico pensando nisso. Abraços.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.